# Records and discriminated union access

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reduce

I would like to make my react reducer function more generic and separate out the action handlers into functions. I have something like this:

```
export type Actions =
  | {
  type: "ADD_COLUMN";
  newColumnIndex: number;
  column: SelectorColumnData;
}
  | {
  type: "ITEM_CHECKED";
  columnIndex: number;
  item: SelectorItem;
};

export type ActionTypes = Actions["type"];
// type ActionTypes = "ADD_COLUMN" | "ITEM_CHECKED";
```

And this makes sense to me:

```
const reducerRecord: Record<ActionTypes, (draft: Draft<SelectorState>, action: Actions) => void> = {
  "ITEM_CHECKED": itemCheckedAction,
  "ADD_COLUMN": addColumnAction,
};

export const selectorReducer: ImmerReducer<SelectorState, Actions> = (
  draft: Draft<SelectorState>,
  action: Actions,
): void => {
  reducerRecord[action.type](draft, action);
};
```

And my action handler:

```
export const itemCheckedAction = (draft: Draft<SelectorState>, action: Actions) => {
  const { columnIndex, item } = action;
  // ...
}
```

TypeScript did not like this (`TS2339: property 'columnIndex' does not exist on type 'Actions'`), so I tried this:

```
export const itemCheckedAction = (draft: Draft<SelectorState>, action: Actions) => {
  const { columnIndex, item }: Extract<Actions, { type: "ITEM_CHECKED" }> = action;
  // ...
}
```

Didn't like this either! It says the "ADD_COLUMN" type is missing.

Strangely, if I write:

```
export const itemCheckedAction = (draft: Draft<SelectorState>, action: Actions) => {
  if(action.type === "ITEM_CHECKED") {
    const { columnIndex, item }: Actions = action;
  }
  // ...
}
```

...hovering over `= action` there shows the expected subtype of the union, but the IDE still complains that `columnIndex` and `item` are not properties of `Actions`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the parameter to be discriminated. The simplest way to do this by intersecting it with the targeted `type` variant:

```
export type Actions =
  | {
  type: "ADD_COLUMN";
  newColumnIndex: number;
  column: never;
}
  | {
  type: "ITEM_CHECKED";
  columnIndex: number;
  item: never;
};

export type ActionTypes = Actions["type"];

export const itemCheckedAction = (draft: never, action: Actions & { type: "ITEM_CHECKED" }) => {
  const { columnIndex, item } = action;
  // ...
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBjGBLCA7AZzgF4BYAKDjgB84BvCqpFALjgCI0ARLgfQGEA8gBkAqgFkAcuwDcjOHmAB3fhAA2AVwC2eAJJ4AJqDZ5tAI2BQ5lOBnXa8J4ADdL1gL7zaDG82Bt2XQAVAFFxAQAJEP4AaRCuWXk7TR19IxATczd5bBhgLSdXKwp3awpQSFgEZFRMHHwgmqJidCxcQgBtdj92AF0y8groeDtCeFz8-gALYAwAa2ADOvaSOAAKAygAQwAzGELLABo4Lbb8NmX8IgAyemrWDmCwyOi4hLh3AEoSAD56JKu8DotnsqUMoGOEy0H1Wp3qeGsVAA9Ei4AA6DElIA)